# Is is possible to make any element other than ActionSet clickable in Actionable message

Tags: adaptive-cards

I know in Microsoft's ActionableMessage, one can have ActionSet which is clickable and you can have it open an URL.

But designs I am working with calls for something like this:

---

### | Some Text.  [Icon] |

Is there a way I can define AdaptiveColumn/AdaptiveColumnSet clickable UI element, such that one can open url?

I have found a kind of "hackable" way, where I have created a background with just icon.
Then I set the text in a column and set text value as [Some Text](https://someurl)

That "kind-of" works but now user has to click on that text. Click on the entire element doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many elements you can make clickable, check this here as an example:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.5",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Clicking this opens google",
        "size": "Medium",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "id": "googleButton"
    },
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "id": "Image",
        "url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTK2nG24AYDm6FOEC7jIfgubO96GbRso2Xshu1f8abSYQ&s",
        "selectAction": {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "url": "https://www.google.de"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "selectAction": {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "url": "https://www.google.de"
        },
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "New TextBlock",
                "wrap": true,
                "selectAction": {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "url": "https://www.google.de"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Many elements such as container, image etc have the "selectAction" property where you can define an onClick action